# Failed audit with Looks OK for a good answer

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

I was reviewing *[Low quality answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review)* and I had chosen option "Looks OK". Here is the review in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/31877496

[image: Screenshot of the audit]

This was an audit for my review and it failed.
In the Answer(s) and Question tabs section, I only had the Question tab and Answer tab with only one answer (the one in question).
This answer was well written as you can see in the link I provided.

If I am looking only at the review and don't go to the question page and investigate if this answer is deleted or downvoted or different from what I can see in the review, I can assess only based on this information.

In this case, the answer should be voted as "Looks OK" because the content was referring to the question and it had a code example and links for referenced documentation.
I can't see why was it deleted in the first place, but it was deleted.

I got two questions:

1. Could this be an example where the chosen audit answer was wrongly chosen by the system since it did not show enough context why should I vote to delete it?
2. Should I always go into the question link from the review page to prevent me from making the same mistake?

Comment: I suspect the user was posting links to a site (possibly the one in the second URL) and not disclosing their affiliation, and when they were banned and/or deleted the community bot deleted all their content as spam; making an unclear audit.

Comment: Hmm, could be the second link in question.

Comment: It was spam; the final link (flowerbrackets.com) is something that has been spammed to this site multiple times, from multiple user accounts. However, there is no reasonable way that you, as a reviewer, could have divined that, since you can't see any information about a deleted user, so unless you just *remembered* seeing a lot of spam for that site, you'd have no reason to even be suspicious. Therefore, this was a bad audit by definition, because audits are supposed to be obvious. I've taken steps to remove it as an audit candidate now.

Comment: That said, you should have easily been able to pass the audit by using the information (breadcrumbs) that the system presented to you in the review queue interface. Didn't it tell you to suspect that it was spam? You could have gone to check the post to see if it had been deleted from the site. That would have been a great clue, and more than enough to pass the audit in order to prove to the system that you were paying attention, not just randomly clicking buttons.

Comment: Indeed, in my experience when the UI tells you that it is potentially spam, 9/10 times it's an audit. Spam tends to get nuked really fast, so you'll hardly run into them into the wild I guess.

Comment: @CodyGray got it. Thanks for the actions you have take and i appreciate your comment. It gives me input to consider. As for the part that was flagged as a spam, i think it did not have that orange box that said that, i may be wrong i cant remember. But i do go into pages with answers and questions when i do reviews, it's just that this time it was obvious that it is a good answer. Maybe i missed that box with "spam message" and did not go into that page to check it out. I will pay more attention for sure. Thanks for your time

Comment: It's not cheating to view the question in another tab.  Audits are designed to be passed.  Viewing the question in a tab, and thus all answers, is part of successfully performing community moderation.

Comment: What do you mean by *"for good a answer"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen two words transposed: "for a good answer"